# Spring SpEL and passing env properties to SpEL method

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-el

I'm trying to use Spring's expression language (SpEL) to pass a property from my `application.yml` file into a SpEL method call.

I'm in a Spring Boot and Spring Security environment, and I'm trying to do this in the `@PreAuthorize` annotation.  I'm able to call the method `hasAuthority()` without issue like so:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('APP_USER')")
```

This works fine.  It verifies the user has the `APP_USER` authorization token.  However, I want to externalize this value to configuration as a property.  This doesn't work:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(#systemProperties.get('app.auth.readToken'))")
```

I've also tried

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(#environment( app.auth.readToken ))")
```

and

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(${app.auth.readToken})")
```

So, how can I use SpEL to pass an application property as a SpEL method parameter?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `PropertyResolver` within the annotation with `@propertyResolver`.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(@propertyResolver.getProperty('app.auth.readToaken'))")
```

---

### Edit:

If this isn't working, you can provide a properties `@Bean` in you configuration to load your properties.  Then just access that bean instead of `propertyResolver`.  Here is example of loading a `yml` file.

```
@Bean
public Properties properties() {
    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yml"));  //the yml file
    return yaml.getObject();
}
```

and used in an annotation...

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(@properties.getProperty('app.auth.readToaken'))")
```

Comment: Hmm, I get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'propertyResolver' available`, which is odd because I am able to use `@Value` and map in properties elsewhere in the class.  Is the bean named differently in Spring 4+ ?

Comment: @heez I've provided another option loading the properties into a `@Bean`.

Comment: Yep :) the second approach is what I did as a workaround.  I ended up using `@Value` to load in the property, and then I access that field using the bean approach.